# ubuntu 22.04 hangs - hard reset helps

Tags: nvidia

I installed ubuntu 22.04.1 I have hardware 12B RAM and GF T 240 old graphics card. I set up the system. Everything works beautifully. Only from time to time there is a suspension. Nothing works, I can not move the mouse. Only a hard reset. What could be the cause?

Comment: Judging from your name we are both Polish and I've got the same problem. A timezone must be the reason ;-)